# Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. How to solve it?

Tags: ios, swift

I views many posts like this, tried few things, but I couldn't get reason of error, neither I could solve it.

I have a custom Class.

```
class Profile: NSObject {
    var PlayerID: Int? = 0
   }
```

I have object in AppDelegate, for this class

```
var profile: Profile!
```

In some other class, I am using

```
if let playerID = appDelegate.profile.PlayerID {

}
```

It gives error

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

What is reason of this error.
How to solve it.

What I tried

```
if let playerID = appDelegate.profile.PlayerID as? Int {

}
```

also I tried

```
if let playerID = appDelegate.profile.PlayerID as Int! {

  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: How the `appDelegate` is declared in your code?

Comment: var appDelegate: AppDelegate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may occur in 3 points in your code

1. if `appDelegate` is nil
2. if `profile` is nil
3. if `playerID` is nil

Try:

```
if let playerID = appDelegate?.profile?.PlayerID {

}
```

You may need to read more about optionals in swift and [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: AppDelegate is Initialised in ViewDidLoad 

        self.appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

Comment: What is relationship of ! ? and .? and as? , can you describe it a little by editing your answer. it would be easy for me to understand. why you used ?. before instance.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your:

```
var profile: Profile!
```

I'm assuming that profile is actually `nil` when you call this line:

```
if let playerID = appDelegate.profile.PlayerID {

}
```

---

Using the `!` operator forces an object to be unwrapped, which can cause a runtime error if the object is `nil` when being accessed.

To be safe, you should change your profile property in the `AppDelegate` to:

```
var profile: Profile?
```

and then use optional chaining in to unwrap the object if it exists:

```
if let playerID = appDelegate.profile?.PlayerID {

}
```

If the profile object exists in the `AppDelegate`, this this will return the `PlayerID`, otherwise it will return `nil` and the code block won't be executed. You need to make sure you are assigning the `profile` to the `AppDelegate` as well at some point.

It's generally good practice to **not** use implicitly unwrapped properties unless you can **absolutely guarantee** that it will not be nil. (Which in most cases, is unlikely)

I hope this helps.